# How to automatically change a sentence to add a word from a list (Google Sheets or Excel)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi there and thank you for any support received in advance!

I have a Google Sheets document (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vKc1u1B_Yz8MOUX7x1dRucrKZepozqft18N_jkVAgX8/edit?usp=sharing) that has a list of towns in it and a series of default questions (about my fishing project).

I would like to be able to run some form of script or code that automatically changes the "XXXXXX" in any sentence and replaces it with a word from the list of towns. There will be 10 questions (once I have finished the project) and each line of the sheet will need to have questions for each individual town (with the name changed). If someone is able to help I would really appreciate it and you can change that document as much as you'd like (it is a demo that I have set up for the purpose of asking this question). I would also appreciate a short explanation as to how you achieve the required result so I can learn and apply this in the future (without having to come back to S.O everytime).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with writing the default question in the header row (see the copy of the sheet I made) then you could use in B3

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A3:A), substitute(B2:C2, "XXXXXX",A3:A),))
```

to create the output in the range B3:C.

[image]

If changing the range of the default questions is not an option you can check out the sheet 'JPV_2' where I entered in cell C3

```
=transpose(Arrayformula(if(len(A3:A), substitute(transpose(B3:B4), "XXXXXX",A3:A),)))
```

[image]

I hope that helps?